# How to push values in array using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a simple logic -
each loop runs for input radio and geting two value ie value of radio btton and name of radio button
Now the alert window only show result of last element 
I want all the array result should be stored in mf
Name is comming dynamically

```js
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
  var1 = $(this).val();
  var2 = $(this).attr("name");
  mf = [var2 + "_" + var1];
});
alert(mf);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />A
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redefining mf instead of adding stuff to it. You should do the following:

```
var mf = [];

$( "input[type=radio]:checked" ).each(function(){
    var1 = $(this).val();
    var2 = $(this).attr("name");
    mf.push(var2+"_"+var1);
}); 
alert(mf) ;
```

First off, declare your variable mf as an array, then in your each loop use the `.push()` function to push data to it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that you're redefining the value of `mf` in each iteration, hence it only holds the final value when the loop ends.

To fix this, use `push()` to add an element to the array:

```js
var mf = [];
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
  var1 = $(this).val();
  var2 = $(this).attr("name");
  mf.push(var2 + "_" + var1);
});
console.log(mf);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />A
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_2" value="2" checked="true" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_3" value="3" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_4" value="4" checked="true" />C
```

Also note that a better method to achieve what you need is to use `map()` to create the array directly from the jQuery object:

```js
var mf =  $("input[type=radio]:checked").map(function() {
  return this.name + "_" + this.value;
}).get();
console.log(mf);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />A
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_2" value="2" checked="true" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_3" value="3" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_4" value="4" checked="true" />C
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Javascript function called `.push()` ([Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)).

So what you do is that you define your `mf` array outside of the `.each()` and then for each iteration of the loop, you push the result into the `mf` array.

```
var mf = [];
$( "input[type=radio]:checked" ).each(function(){
    var1 = $(this).val();
    var2 = $(this).attr("name");
    mf.push(var2+"_"+var1);
});

// mf = ["name1_val1", "name2_val2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mf = [];

$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
  var1 = $(this).val();
  var2 = $(this).attr("name");
  mf.push(var1)
  mf.push(var2)
});
console.log(mf);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" checked/>A
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />B
<input type="radio" name="r_1q_1" value="1" />C
```

Use `.push()`

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you...!!

```js
var mf = [];
$(document).on('click','input[type=radio]',function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
   mf.push($(this).val()+"_"+$(this).attr("name")) ;
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="radio"  name="r_1q_1" value="1" />A
    <input  type="radio"  name="r_1q_1" value="2" />B
      <input  type="radio"  name="r_1q_1" value="3" />B
        <input  type="radio"  name="r_1q_1" value="4" />C
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  var studentList =[];
  var emailAddresses=[];
  $('table tr').each(function (i, row) {
  var tr =$(row);
  var chk= tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
  console.log(chk)
  if(chk){
      emailAddresses.push(tr.find('.email').text())
      studentList.push(tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('id'))
      console.log(emailAddresses);
      console.log(studentList);        
     }
  });
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7deSTemD8mWryJNMOg7?p=preview)

Comment: This appears to have no relation to the question being asked (eg, where did `table tr` and `.email` come from?).   At the very minimum, it needs some text explaining how it solves the problem.   A good answer will indicate how any code provided fits the situation - don't just copy+paste some code that solved a vaguely related issue.